# Smartface.io ibeacon crash

Tags: ios, ibeacon, smartface.io

I have downloaded sample app from https://github.com/smartface/Sample-Projects/tree/master/iBeacon, and followed tutorial on http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/advanced/ibeacon/#broadcasting

When I click the "Monitor Beacons" button in Smartface companion app it just crash. The same ting happens when I run it in a xcode project on my Mac.

This is where it crashes `SMF.Bluetooth.BLE.startMonitoringForRegion`.

Error in xcode: `exc bad access code 1`

iPhone 5, Version: 7.1.2 (11d257)

Anyone had this problem before and know a solution?

```
var beaconRegion = new SMF.Bluetooth.BLE.BeaconRegion({
        proximityUUID : "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D",
        identifier : "io.smartface.beaconapp",
        major : 1,
        minor : 1
    });

**SMF.Bluetooth.BLE.startMonitoringForRegion({**
    region : beaconRegion,
    onEnterRegion : function (e) {
        alert("Enter region: " + JSON.stringify(e));
        SMF.Bluetooth.BLE.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug now and it is going to be fixed with Smartface App Studio 4.3.1

Thank you for your feedbacks.

Comment: Any ETA on Smartface App Studio 4.3.1?

Comment: You can get direct patch, If you are licensed customer without waiting 4.3.1 release . It takes 3 weeks to release the new 4.3.1 version.

Comment: May I know when version 4.3.1 will release for the iBeacons fix?